# PHP add K,M abbreviation to integer

Tags: php

I have this function for abbreviating an integer with `K` or `M` units:

```
function infVal($n, $prec = 3)
{
    $size = preg_replace('/[^0-9]/', '', $n);
    $sizes = array("", "K", "M");

    if ($size == 0) { 
        return 'n/a'; 
    } 

    return round($size/pow(1000, ($i = floor(log($size, 1000)))), 0) . $sizes[$i];
}
```

However, this function fails when `$n = 999999`, displays `1000K` instead of `999K`.

Can you help?

Comment: The parameter `$prec` seems to be unused, is that right?

Comment: It doesn't actually fail, it just rounds up `999.999` to `1000`, that is all. What did you expect, did you just want to cut the fraction off?

Answer (score -1):

If you want to cut the fraction off, use `floor()` instead of `round()`:

```
function infVal($n)
{
    $size = preg_replace('/[^0-9]/', '', $n);
    $sizes = array("", "K", "M");

    if ($size == 0) { 
        return 'n/a'; 
    } 

    return floor($size/pow(1000, ($i = floor(log($size, 1000))))) . $sizes[$i];
```

}

**Note** I removed the unused argument `$prec`.

For reference, see:

- http://php.net/manual/en/function.floor.php

For an example, see:

- https://3v4l.org/RflXI